# Storing a foreign key for the main primary key in each table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ef-core-2.0

Say we have the table `Users` with an `ID` as a primary key, and the user has the following related entities:

```
UserSubjects(SubjectId <PK>,UserId <FK>)
SubjectPapers(PaperId<PK>,SubjectId<FK>)
```

Now as per the above tables, for security reasons the `userId` must be passed as a parameter to get all the `SubjectPapers` for a `Subject` that are related to the user instead of just passing the `SubjectId`.

take that method for example:

```cs
 public List<SubjectPaper> GetBySubject(int userId, int subjectId)
 {
     return _context.SubjectPapers
         .Include(k => k.UserSubject)
         .Where(k => k.SubjectId == subjectId && k.UserSubject.UserId == userId)
         .ToList();
 }
```

In the above method, the user has to be included in the query to validate that he is making the request to get one of his subjects.

What if also `SubjectPapers` has more related entities theoretically. Will storing a `UserId` Foreign key improve the query's performance by adding a non-clustered index on both columns (UserId and SubjectId)? Is there any side effects? or is there any other way to avoid including the parent user each related entity? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If UserId is requried to find a Subject, then Subject is a "[Weak Entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity)" and the UserID should be the leading column in it's compound primary key.

```
UserSubjects(UserId <PK,FK>,SubjectId <PK>)
```

IE like

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { set; } = new HashSet<Subject>();
}
public class Subject
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public virtual User UserId { get; set; }
}
```

and configured like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>().HasKey(s => new { s.UserID, s.SubjectId });
modelBuilder.Entity<Subject>().Property(s => s.SubjectId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

This optimizes for retrieval by UserID and prevents the Subject table from requiring multiple indexes.  It has a single clustered index  on (UserID,SubjectID) instead of needing two separate indexes on the two columns.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out using multiple primary keys for `UserSubjects`, but what about the main question which is the second related table `SubjectPapers`, that will always require to include the parent table `UserSubject` to validate the `UserId`?

Comment: It's a modeling decision.  But if you want to retrieve those grandchild rows with a UserID yes.  The whole hierarchy or "cluster" of weak entitiy tables get compound primary keys.  So SubjectPapers would have (UserId,SubjectId,SubjectPaperId) as its key.

Comment: Great! but in the case of the method I'm using above I would also introduce a non-clustered index to both `UserId and SubjecId`

Comment: The clustered primary key on (UserId, SubjectId) is sufficient.  The rule for indexes is that you need one for every key, and for every foreign key.  Here a single compound index does both.  If you _also_ want efficient lookup or uniqueness by just SubjectId, then you can a non-clustered index on SubjectId.

Comment: yes,I ment for the second table that has 3 PKs (UserId,SubjectId,SubjectPaperId) that would be retrieved by (UserId,SubjectId)

Comment: That's one PK with three columns.  And it might not need any non-clustered indexes at all.